# AVAudioPlayer stops

Tags: avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a mp3 file with using `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
NSString *path = NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@" , 
    [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];


[player play];
NSLog(@"%f/%f", player.currentTime, player.duration);
```

However, the player stops around 478.558367 every time even though its duration is 1044.437506.
Why does the player stop in the middle of the track?

Comment: try to play the audio in your computer and check as a first step and also use another audio file in your code, If the problem is persistence we ll dig some more.

Comment: I tried another mp3 file and it worked. I guess the mp3 file that I used caused the problem. Thanks.